# Why did not open the view of a button type ir.actions.act_window?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am creating a button in the model sale.order that pressing the button will now have the stock.picking.form .
This is my my sale_view.xml file

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="vista_stock_picking">
    <field name="name">Vista stock picking</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

And in Form view sale.order model , I created the button:

```
<button name="%(vista_stock_picking)d" string="Vista stock picking" type="action"/>
```

I checked the documentation Odoo but I had no clear information .

If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: When I click the button nothing happens, and does not show me the  stock.picking.form view

Comment: try to add the module_name.action_id

Comment: what is your module name ?

Comment: The button is in the sale.order model (sale module) and want to go to stock.picking.form view.

Comment: i don't mean the model i mean the module the whole module name

Comment: It's the sale module

Comment: There are plenty example for this one, you can find by searching in other modules. However.. [Here is Link](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/how-to-open-a-form-from-a-view-button-37937)

Comment: are you want to open Incoming Shipment tree/form view or Delivery Order tree/form view ?

Comment: i want to open this view:

Inventory /My Company: Receipts / New

(stock.picking.form)

Answer (score 0):

There's a field view_mode required for creating window actions in odoo. By default it is tree,form. So possibly this might be the cause, You can try to add the view_mode in the window action definition like,

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="vista_stock_picking">
  <field name="name">Vista stock picking</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">form</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
  <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

Also make sure that the window action should load before the button. Otherwise it won't find what the id you are looking for. If both are in single file then window action should be placed first and then the button. If both are in different files then make sure first to call the file that contains window action in **__openerp__.py** and then the file with button.
If stills not works then try to add the module name in front of window action id,

```
<button name="%(module_name.vista_stock_picking)d" string="Vista stock picking" type="action"/>
```

Comment: I did exactly that you said me , i create a field.xml and i added it in __openerp__.py. Also add the button in the sale_view.xml in sale.order.form view. But the trace shows me the following error:

ParseError: "Invalid model name in the action definition in this line:

<record id="stock.vista_stock_picking" model="ir.actions.act_window">...

and the sentence is correct.

Comment: this is my file.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
       <record id="stock.vista_stock_picking" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Vista stock picking</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record> 
    </data>
</openerp>

Comment: Your id is stock.vista_stock_picking. Why do you want this type of id. Do you want this window act directly in stock module? Your field.xml should load before custom sale_view.xml in __openerp__.py